# extract raster names by points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-conversion, aggregate-points

I use ArcGIS 10.2.2 and I have a problem with some frames extracted from a video. I have the frames (more then 1000) georeferend and I have a track file with the corresponding points.

I wrote down information on the singel frames corresponding to the name of the frames (jpgs numbered from 0 upwards, like "C4_dolo1_3_conv_MOD.avi_0"). I would like an operation that extracts the NAMES of the frames to the points from the track file - or only the number of the frame to some georeferenced outline of the georeferenced frames.

The attribute data are written down per extracted and georeferenced Videoframe. So the attributes have no spatial information yet. That is why I want to create a shapefile with a field with the names of the rasters - so that I can then join the attributes to that field.

Does anyone have an idea what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You could start building the extent of your raster as polygon (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/get-boundary-of-raster-image-as-polygon-in-arcgis-desktop) for different methods). Then you just need to use a [spatial join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) (CLOSEST) to extract the values per point.

Comment: I would need the Frame number as ID to join my table to it. So a spatial join would not do it.

Comment: I don't understand where you have a problem. Spatial join (a join by location) does not require attribute matching.

Comment: I was unprecise about my problem - the attribute data are written down per extracted and georeferenced Videoframe. So the attributes have no spatial information yet - so no spatial join is possible. That is why I need to create a shapefile with a field with the names of the rasters - that I can then join the attributes to.

Comment: Please edit your question. I will then delete my answer (which will remove the associated comments) because I didn't catch that your data was not georeferenced