# How do you open the Symbol Selector in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, symbology

Normally, I think, you can open the Symbol selector by clicking any of the boxes that is shown as part of the legend below a file in Table of Contents. However, when I try this for a certain file (a tif raster file) it opens the Color Selector instead of the Symbol Selector. Why do you think this is and is there a way for me to access the Symbol Selector?

I want to access the Symbol Selector in order to put a frame around the whole raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are raster layers, not vector.  You cannot apply symbology to a raster, rather you adjust how to display it by modifying color settings.

If you want to display a frame around the raster you will need to create a polygon layer and draw the edge around the boundary of your image.  You can then display that polygon outline as the frame around your image.

See also [Get boundary of raster image as polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/get-boundary-of-raster-image-as-polygon-in-arcgis-desktop)

Comment: I was hoping for a magical solution as well, like a checkbox "Outline Raster boundaries" or something like that. Guess i'll keep on doing this!

Comment: @Louis see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/get-boundary-of-raster-image-as-polygon-in-arcgis-desktop

Comment: @Midavalo Huh, neat! never thought of that before, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is only sort of true. Take an image, run a classification on it and the classes in the resultant image can be styled, based on the column "VALUE", using the symbol selector. Change the column on which the symbology should be based and suddenly you cannot acces the symbol selector anymore.
The latter may be correct behaviour but it is confusingly inconsistent.