# Create outer polygon using raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, vector, borders

How to create the outlet border only  while using raster data in ArcMap? I am already using raster to vector converting format but it did not help.

[image: I need outer polygon like this]

Can you tell me or explain about other way?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your image has NoData values around the edges. I would try [reclassifying the image](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) to a binary raster (1 = Data, 0 = No Data), and then trying raster to vector.

The GIS SE question [Getting boundary of raster image as polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/getting-boundary-of-raster-image-as-polygon-in-arcgis-desktop) asked about getting the boundaries of the entire image (NoData included), but it still looks to have some useful suggestions in the answers.