# Snapping polygon to raster cells using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, snapping

I'm working with raster datasets that all share the same raster cells. I have a polygon that clips out an area of interest from these datasets, but it isn't aligned with the raster cells.

Is there a simple way to snap this polygon to the raster cells using ArcMap?

To illustrate, I want this polygon line to snap to the raster cells (on all sides of the polygon):

[image: polygon line not aligned with raster cells]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To snap the clip operation itself to the cell raster use `Environment -> Processing Extent -> Snap Raster` option, where you specify e.g. the raster that you're clipping.

To get a "snapped polygon", then use the snap-clipped raster and the tool `Raster Domain` (available with 3D analyst license) to produce a polygon. If you don't have this license, see other ways [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/getting-boundary-of-raster-image-as-polygon-in-arcgis-desktop).

It will look like this (being snapped to the centers of the outer raster cells - clipping operations w/o Snap Raster will work fine):
[image]