# Extracting Raster Footprint in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, extents, footprint

I suspect this question already exists, but I have been unsuccessful in finding one yet.

I have a series of 9 rasters (PNG files) in ArcMap.  I need the footprint (or extent) of each of these rasters as polygons, however I can't find a tool that will do this for me.  I found one that extracts from Mosaic, and another that uses the Defense extension (which I don't have).

How can I extract the polygon footprint of a raster in ArcMap?  I'm using ArcGIS 10.7.1

Comment: The Stack Answer is shared below: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22011/getting-boundary-of-raster-image-as-polygon-in-arcgis-desktop

Comment: That's the one, thank you @YogeshChavan !

Comment: And the answer that worked for me (the only one I tired) was using Raster Domain from the 3D Analyst toolbox.

Comment: There is this tool which will create a single feature class of polygons for all of the raster extents in a single directory. https://github.com/LummiGIS/Raster_Extents_To_Polygons.  This should work for 10.1 and later versions of ArcGIS.

Comment: @GBG That sounds useful, but all I can see is the License - am I missing it somewhere?

Comment: @Midavalo - Oops, failed to commit, ID-10T error.  Try again, you should see the Python script and the toolbox now.